# Java Socket : java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: java, sockets, timeout

Hi I hope you guys are doing great.

I'm currently trying to test a service class that creates a socket connection to a print server.

Here's the service class :

```
public class PrintServiceImpl implements PrintService {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PrintServiceImpl.class);

static final int TIMEOUT_MILLISECOND = 20000;

@Override
public boolean sendLabelToPrintServer(String hostname, int port, String labelData) {

    Socket clientSocket = null;
    DataOutputStream outToServer = null;
    Boolean successful;

    try {
        // open the connection to the printing server
        clientSocket = new Socket();
        clientSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port), TIMEOUT_MILLISECOND);
        clientSocket.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT_MILLISECOND);

        outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        // send data to print
        outToServer.writeBytes(labelData);

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        // Read HTTP Request CHARACTER BY CHARACTER instead of line by line
        while ((char) input.read() != 0 && (char) input.read() != '\r') {
            LOGGER.debug("Getting print server answer.");
        }

        successful = true;
        LOGGER.debug("Label printed.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Printing failed.", e);
        successful = false;
    } finally {
        try {
            // close connection
            if (outToServer != null) {
                outToServer.close();
            }
            if (clientSocket != null) {
                clientSocket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception while closing DataOutputStream/ClientSocket.", e);
        }
    }
    return successful;
}
```

And here's my test class. As you can see the @Before method instantiates a SocketServer on a new Thread.

```
public class PrintServiceImplTest {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PrintServiceImplTest.class);

PrintServiceImpl whfPrintService = new PrintServiceImpl();

private static final String LOCALHOST = "localhost";
private static final int SERVER_PORT = 3000;
private static final String LABEL_TEXT = "This dummy text is sent to the print server";
private static final String RESPONSE = "Test Label printed correctly";
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket incommingSocket = null;

@Before
public void before() {
    Thread myThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
                incommingSocket = server.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    myThread.start();
}

@After
public void after() {
    try {
        incommingSocket.close();
        server.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Test
public void returnsTrueIfConnectionSuccessful() {

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String line;

    whfPrintService.sendLabelToPrintServer(LOCALHOST, SERVER_PORT, LABEL_TEXT);

    try {

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incommingSocket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(incommingSocket.getOutputStream());

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incommingSocket.getInputStream()));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("line : " + line);
        }

        out.write(RESPONSE);
        out.flush();

        out.close();
        in.close();
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run the test, I get a SocketTimoutException. It occurs when the client is reading the response from the server. This line :

```
while ((char) input.read() != 0 && (char) input.read() != '\r') {
```

So this means that the client does not receive a response. My guess is that the server does not send a correct response.

What am I missing ? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Improper server->client response

You response doesn't end with a `\0` or a `\r`.

> ```
> private static final String RESPONSE = "Test Label printed correctly";
> ```

By making your response end with either of those characters, the client will escape from the loop.

```
private static final String RESPONSE = "Test Label printed correctly\0";
```

### Client reads response incorrectly

The client reads the response using the following code:

> ```
> while ((char) input.read() != 0 && (char) input.read() != '\r') {
> ```

Every call to `input.read()` returns a new byte from the network. You should call `input.read()` one time every while loop, and compare after it.

```
char c;
while (c = (char) input.read()) != -1) {
    if(c == 0 || c == '\r') {
        break;
    }
}
```

### Client to server message has no proper ending

Messages send from the client to server have no ending, the server reads until the socket input is closed, but the client never closes the socket.

> ```
>   // send data to print
>    outToServer.writeBytes(labelData);
> ```

After you wrote those bytes, call [`socket.shutdownOutput()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#shutdownOutput()) to signal end of file to the other party.

```
  // send data to print
   outToServer.writeBytes(labelData);
  clientSocket.shutdownOutput();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right. But the problem remains. Do you see anything else that could be source of my issue ?

Comment: I added a paragraph called "Client reads response incorrectly" with another bug

Comment: Yes, I agree it's better like this. However is still doesn't solve the problem. Something I noticed is that I get the timeout first and only then "This dummy text is sent to the print server" gets printed in the console.

Comment: Can you call `clientSocket.shutdownOutput();` after you write the bytes from the client?

Comment: Same result. Don't you think the problem comes from the way I try to send a message from the server ? I'm not really sure I'm using this PrintWriter.write method correctly.